# How to download files using HttpClient with a ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, httpclient, .net-6.0

I created a new class named `SiteDownload` and added some links to download images:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class SiteDownload
    {
        public static List<string> Sites()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            list.Add("mysite.com/sites/default/files/1231105.gif");
            list.Add("mysite.com/sites/default/files/1231040.gif");

        return list;
        }

        public static async Task<List<Website>> ParallelDownload(IProgress<ProgressReport> progress, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
        {
            List<string> sites = Sites();
            List<Website> list = new List<Website>();
            ProgressReport progressReport = new ProgressReport();
            ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
            parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8;
            parallelOptions.CancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach<string>(sites, parallelOptions, (site) =>
                    {
                        Website results = Download(site);
                        list.Add(results);
                        progressReport.SitesDownloaded = list;
                        progressReport.PercentageComplete = (list.Count * 100) / sites.Count;
                        progress.Report(progressReport);
                        parallelOptions.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    });
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            });

            return list;
        }

        private static Website Download(string url)
        {
            Website website = new Website();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            website.Url = url;
            website.Data = client.DownloadString(url);
            return website;
        }

        public class Website
        {
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public string Data { get; set; }
        }

        public class ProgressReport
        {
            public int PercentageComplete { get; set; }
            public List<Website> SitesDownloaded { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

in `form1`:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static HttpClientFilesDownloader.SiteDownload;

namespace HttpClientFilesDownloader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void PrintResults(List<Website> results)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in results)
                richTextBox1.Text += $"{item.Url} downloaded: {item.Data.Length} characters long.{Environment.NewLine}";
        }

        void ReportProgress(object sender, ProgressReport e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.PercentageComplete;
            label1.Text = $"Completed: {e.PercentageComplete} %";
            PrintResults(e.SitesDownloaded);
        }

        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                Progress<ProgressReport> progress = new Progress<ProgressReport>();
                progress.ProgressChanged += ReportProgress;
                var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var results = await SiteDownload.ParallelDownload(progress, cancellationTokenSource);
                PrintResults(results);
                watch.Stop();
                var elapsed = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                richTextBox1.Text += $"Total execution time: {elapsed}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    } 
}
```

The desiger

[image: designer]

When I click the START button, nothing happens. I don't see the `progressBar` get any process and the `label1` is not updating and nothing in the RichTextBox. It's just not downloading the images.
I'm not getting any errors, it's just not downloading.

I took this example from this site just instead downloading site/s I'm trying to download images files and save them on the hard disk as images:

[example](https://foxlearn.com/windows-forms/parallel-download-in-csharp-356.html)

I also need to add header like i did with webclient:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
```

but not sure how to add the headers to the HttpClient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example of a HTTP resource downloader.  This class is meant to target .NET 6+, since it's using [Parallel.ForEachAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync).  The [record keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) requires C# 9+. `Nullable` enabled

I tried to keep the structure you have used in the OP as much as possible

To start the download of a collection of resources, call the static `Download()` method, passing an `IProgress<ProgressReport>` delegate, a collection of strings representing the URLs of the resources and a CancellationTokenSource

The `ReportProgress()` method marshals to the UI Thread a `ProgressReport` record.   It references a `WebData` record, which contains the URL of the current resource, the image (in this case) bytes, the `Completed` status and the Exception thrown in case the resource failed to download for some reason. If the download is canceled in the meantime, the Exception reason is going to be `The operation was canceled`.
It also returns the overall progress of the downloads, in the form of a percentage.
Note that the progress procedure is completed also when you cancel the operation, since you probably want to know which resource was completed before the operation was canceled and which one couldn't complete

**Note:** the static `Download()` method is not Thread-Safe, i.e., you cannot call this method concurrently, e.g., to download multiple lists of resources at the same time (though it can be easily refactored, making it non-static).
Check the `IsBusy` Property before you call that method again.

```
public class ResourceDownloader {

    private static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> client = new(() => {
        SocketsHttpHandler handler = CreateHandler(autoRedirect: true);

        var client = new HttpClient(handler, true) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        // Keep true if you download resources from different collections of URLs each time
        // Remove or set to false if you use the same URLs multiple times and frequently
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
        return client;
    }, true);

    private static SocketsHttpHandler CreateHandler(bool autoRedirect)
    {
        return new SocketsHttpHandler() {
            AllowAutoRedirect = autoRedirect,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2) // <= Adjust as required
        };
    }

    public record WebData(string Url, byte[]? Data, bool Completed = true, Exception? Ex = null);
    public record ProgressReport(WebData Site, int PercentageComplete);

    private static object syncObj = new object();
    private static ConcurrentBag<WebData> processed = default!;
    private static int progressCount = 0;
    private static int totalCount = 0;

    public static bool IsBusy { get; internal set; } = false;

    public static async Task<List<WebData>> Download(IProgress<ProgressReport> progress, IList<string> sites, CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        processed = new ConcurrentBag<WebData>();
        progressCount = 0;
        totalCount = sites.Count;

        try {
            ParallelOptions options = new() {
                // If it's a single web site, set a value that doesn't get you black-listed
                // Otherwise, increase the value 
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8,
                CancellationToken = cts.Token
            };

            await Parallel.ForEachAsync(sites, options, async (site, token) => {
                try {
                    var dataBytes = await client.Value.GetByteArrayAsync(site, token);
                    ReportProgress(progress, dataBytes, site, null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ReportProgress(progress, null, site, ex);
                }
            });
        }
         // To Debug / Log
        catch (TaskCanceledException) { Debug.Print("The operation was canceled"); }
        finally { IsBusy = false; }
        return processed.ToList();
    }

    private static void ReportProgress(IProgress<ProgressReport> progress, byte[]? data, string site, Exception? ex) {
        lock (syncObj) {
            progressCount += 1;
            var percentage = progressCount * 100 / totalCount;
            WebData webData = new(site, data, ex is null, ex);
            processed.Add(webData);
            progress.Report(new ProgressReport(webData, percentage));
        }
    }
}
```

You can setup a Form like this:

- Add a TextBox (here, named `logger`) to show the status of the resources that are being downloaded
- A Button used to start the download (named `btnStartDownload`)
- A Button to cancel the download (named `btnStopDownload`)
- A ProgressBar (named `progressBar`) used to show the overall progress

Note that with an active (not configured) debugger, you may have notifications that Exceptions are thrown, so maybe run the Project with `CTRL + F5`

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form {
    public SomeForm() => InitializeComponent();

    internal List<string> Sites()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        list.Add("https://somesite/someresource.jpg");
        // [...] add more URLs
        return list;
    }

    IProgress<ResourceDownloader.ProgressReport>? downloadProgress = null;
    CancellationTokenSource? cts = null;

    private void Updater(ResourceDownloader.ProgressReport progress)
    {
        StringBuilder log = new(1024);
        if (progress.Site.Completed) {
            log.Append($"Success! \t {progress.Site.Url}\r\n");
        }
        else {
            log.Append($"Failed! \t {progress.Site.Url}\r\n");
            log.Append($"\tReason: {progress.Site.Ex?.Message}\r\n");
        }
        logger.AppendText(log.ToString());
        progressBar.Value = progress.PercentageComplete;
    }

    private async void btnStartDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ResourceDownloader.IsBusy) return;
        var sites = Sites();

        // This collection will contain the status (and data) of all downloads in th end
        List<ResourceDownloader.WebData>? downloads = null;

        using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
            downloadProgress = new Progress<ResourceDownloader.ProgressReport>(Updater);
            downloads = await ResourceDownloader.Download(downloadProgress, sites, cts);
        }
    }

    private void btnStopDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => cts?.Cancel();
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: ParallelAsync Downloader]

Comment: getting some errors.  this line : public record Website(string Url, byte[]? Data, bool Completed = true, Exception? Ex = null);  on the Url , Data , Completed , Ex same error Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' is not defined or imported HttpClientFilesDownloader D:\Csharp\HttpClientFilesDownloader\ResourceDownloader.cs 38 Active also there is a warning on the ? 
 The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.

Comment: same predefined errors on this line public record ProgressReport(Website Site, int PercentageComplete);

Comment: and var dataBytes = await client.Value.GetByteArrayAsync is not getting two arguments but only one GetByteArrayAsync(site, token); No overload for method 'GetByteArrayAsync' takes 2 arguments

Comment: i changed added language version line 9.0 inside the <PropertyGroup> <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion> in the file HttpClientFilesDownloader.csproj still getting this errors.

Comment: As described, this code is meant to target .Net 6+, not .Net Framework. Hence, you need a .Net 6 or .Net 7 Project with `nullable` enabled

Comment: another thing i noticed it's taking a lot of time to download.  each some seconds it's downloading group of files then wait almost 10-15 seconds and download again.  when i used webclient it was downloading the images very fast not parallel one by one but very fast. why with the httpclient method it's downloading that way ?

Comment: How did you test this when you said you couldn't build a .Net 6 Project? Or are you referring to the animation I've posted? If that's the case, I chose on purpose some sites that respond very slowly, some very quickly. If I had used only the quick response sites, the whole thing would have completed in under 200ms (i.e., no time to press the Cancel button)

Comment: i tested it using your solution i created a .net 6 project not .net framework that was my mistake and it's working.  for some reason the images i'm downloading with your solution each 10-15 seconds it's downloadin block of 8 images then waiting another 10-15 seconds and downloading another 8 images and so on.  it's not downloading them at real time but with some delay and then download group of images each time.  the same links of images when i'm using webclient they are downloading one by one not parallel but it's taking with the webclient maybe 5 seconds more or less to download them all.

Comment: i can upload my project using your solution to here with a link.

Comment: link for form1 in my project : https://pastebin.com/t3w5UaH1 and link for the Radar class that generate the links to download the images.,  https://pastebin.com/79ePfjet the class ResourceDownloader i didn't change this class : https://pastebin.com/f3UDtM5T

Comment: Did you test this with other web sites? Also, setting, e.g., `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16`? I've tested this class with a load of images. All the resources that are handed back quickly are loaded almost immediately, all the slower ones complete in the end, but I don't see any delay between *batches* -- The site you're referring to is not answering to me

Comment: Since you apparently are connection to the same web site, set `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;`, or remove this setting entirely -- There's also the chance that a Server that receives multiple requests from the same address at the same time, may impose some limits to the connections you can open or the number of simultaneous requests

Comment: @Jimi where does it save the downloaded images if at all? I managed to make it working. but I can't see where the images have been saved o the hard disk.

Comment: @OledNeduda The `ResourceDownloader` class uses a `ProgressReport` object to notify when each file is downloaded. The `ProgressReport` object transfers a WebData record which contains the images in a byte array. In the Form here, the `Updater()` method is called each time a `ProgressReport` object is completed. You take the byte array it contains and use `File.WriteAllBytes()` to store the image to disk. The name of the Image should be the section part of the URL string, so you can take it from there. If your URLs don't have a file name, you have to add that information to the WebData record

Comment: @Jimi I tried this. the name is just for the testing.  but I'm getting on the right side on the bytes[] a green line and a message: Possible null reference argument for parameter 'bytes' in 'void File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)'. this is how I did it: if (progress.Site.Completed)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\ttt.png", progress.Site.Data);
                log.Append($"Success! \t {progress.Site.Url}\r\n");
            } the warning is on the part: progress.Site.Data

Comment: @OledNeduda The `Data` property is declared as `byte[]?`, not `byte[]`, it's nullable. You need to add a check for null before using it, otherwise you get a warning because you may be accessing / dereferencing a `null`  value / pointer

Comment: @Jimi did it already and it's working.

Comment: @Jimi the problem now is that if I'm downloading a large file like 1GB for example I need to set the timeout for something higher then 60 seconds.  but if I'm downloading small files I want the timeout to be 60 seconds.  downloading large file/s is working but then I need to change the timeout.

Comment: @OledNeduda Not sure what the TimeOut setting has to do with the size of the data you're downloading. If you mean you want to cancel a download when it takes more than what's expected, you can pass a CancellationToken with a TimeOut set, so you cancel the Task after a specified interval has elapsed. I think you really need to post a new question for this. This comment section is getting too long