# Downloading small files takes very long

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing, httpclient, .net-6.0

I have a `HttpClient` and try to download roughly 25k 6byte size files into ram in order to generate a SHA256 key from it.

I have tried to make it parallel to the best of my ability but couldn't see a change in speed at all.

###### The wrapping function which is starting the download tasks in parallel:

```
SemaphoreSlim downloadConcurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(40);
ConcurrentQueue<Task> Sha256Tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task>();
foreach (string url in urls)
{
    var t = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await downloadConcurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await uploadedFile.CalculateChecksum();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            { } // breakpoint for debugging
        }
        finally
        {
            downloadConcurrencySemaphore.Release();
        }
    });
    Sha256Tasks.Enqueue(t);
}
Task.WaitAll(Sha256Tasks.ToArray());
```

###### The `CalculateChecksum` called by wrapping function, downloads file and generates sha256sum from byte array resulting from download:

```
public async Task CalculateChecksum()
{ // is beeing called up to 40 times in parallel (connection limit)
    byte[] file = await API.DownloadClient.Download(URL);
    Sha256Sum = Sha256.GetSha256Sum(file);
}
```

###### The `DownloadClient` class being called in parallel to download the files:

```
internal static class DownloadClient
{
    static DownloadClient()
    {
        _Client = new HttpClient();
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 40;

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
        handler.MaxConnectionsPerServer = 40;

        _Client = new HttpClient(handler);
    }
    private static HttpClient _Client;
    internal static async Task<byte[]> Download(string url)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _Client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = response.Content;
        byte[] file = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        return file;
    }
}
```

Any Idea on how to make the process faster?
Right now it takes ~15 minutes for ~5.5mb of files, processor and network barely used, program is idling around, waiting for downloads.

Comment: No matter how much you try to parallelize, if the endpoint/backend you are requesting the data from can't keep up with your many concurrent requests or intentionally throttles when exposed to concurrent requests (from the same IP address or so), well, that's it then...

Comment: Could you test [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103) (.Net 6+), to see how it goes with different `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` settings and also changing the HttClient's `DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose` value? `MaxConnectionsPerServer` is the ~equivalent of what you're setting now

Comment: changed it from synchronous to async recently.

Comment: Hmm, what is the value [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit) and what if you increase it (right at the start of your program before it does any HttpClient-related stuff)? Does it improve things?

Comment: @Jimi connectionClose to true or false?

Comment: Both. To see how the Server reacts. Try with `false` first (or comment out that property, same thing) -- Try to synchronize `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and `MaxConnectionsPerServer`

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace in theory this affects the clients internal connection limit.
`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` should be global whereas `handler.MaxConnectionsPerServer = 40;` rhould be client specific. Neither of which made much of a difference. 
Files should be located on decentralized servers...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias changed that. no change. Target framework is .net 6

Comment: You could try replacing the parallelizing code with the simpler and more lightweight [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method (usage example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda/68901782#68901782)), but I don't expect significant improvement in the overall performance.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you run the code without the debugger attached? (with Ctrl+F5)

Comment: Also could you try running the code with different `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` configurations (like 10, 20, 50, 100), and report how this affects the overall performance?

Comment: hmm. After the other changes + maxdegree of parallelissm (max 1000 concurrent requests)
The files are downloaded in a matter of seconds. Throws some httprequest exception though. Ill ty to tune it down to a more reasonable level.

Comment: Did you test the class in the post I've linked? It handles exceptions and reports back (if needed) in case you need to know what files could be processed and the reason why that happened -- If you get stopping exceptions while debugging it's because you didn't configure the debugger. As mentioned, you can start without debugger and log the HTTP / other exceptions

Comment: You can't expect to have your CPU utilized because sha256 takes no time compared to fetching file from remote web server. And reasonable web server will not allow you to issue enough requests concurrently to utilize your CPU.

Comment: Don’t create new HttpClients for every request. This is extremely  expensive as it needs to reserve a port from the OS. Instead have one instance and reuse it. HttpClient is thread-safe.