# Why I can't get access to the class ResourceDownloader from form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

ResourceDownloader is not exist when I try to type it in form1.
and the class is public.

I tried to type in form1: resource_d but it's not exist.
Then I tried: Download_Files.reso    but not exist either.

I want to use the class in form1.
not sure why I can get access to the class.

Tried what I stated above.

This code comes from here:
[How to download files using HttpClient with a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Download_Files
{
    public class ResourceDownloader
    {

        private static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> client = new(() => {
            HttpClientHandler handler = CreateHandler(autoRedirect: true);

            var client = new HttpClient(handler, true) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            // Keep true if you download resources from different collections of URLs each time
            // Remove or set to false if you use the same URLs multiple times and frequently
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
            return client;
        }, true);

        private static HttpClientHandler CreateHandler(bool autoRedirect)
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = autoRedirect,
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };
        }

        public record WebData(string Url, byte[]? Data, bool Completed = true, Exception? Ex = null);
        public record ProgressReport(WebData Site, int PercentageComplete);

        private static object syncObj = new object();
        private static ConcurrentBag<WebData> processed = default!;
        private static int progressCount = 0;
        private static int totalCount = 0;

        public static bool IsBusy { get; internal set; } = false;

        public static async Task<List<WebData>> Download(IProgress<ProgressReport> progress, IList<string> sites, CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            processed = new ConcurrentBag<WebData>();
            progressCount = 0;
            totalCount = sites.Count;

            try
            {
                ParallelOptions options = new()
                {
                    // If it's a single web site, set a value that doesn't get you black-listed
                    // Otherwise, increase the value 
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8,
                    CancellationToken = cts.Token
                };

                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(sites, options, async (site, token) => {
                    try
                    {
                        var dataBytes = await client.Value.GetByteArrayAsync(site, token);
                        ReportProgress(progress, dataBytes, site, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ReportProgress(progress, null, site, ex);
                    }
                });
            }
            // To Debug / Log
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { Debug.Print("The operation was canceled"); }
            finally { IsBusy = false; }
            return processed.ToList();
        }

        private static void ReportProgress(IProgress<ProgressReport> progress, byte[]? data, string site, Exception? ex)
        {
            lock (syncObj)
            {
                progressCount += 1;
                var percentage = progressCount * 100 / totalCount;
                WebData webData = new(site, data, ex is null, ex);
                processed.Add(webData);
                progress.Report(new ProgressReport(webData, percentage));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have presented here comes from this Q&A: [How to download files using HttpClient with a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103), you cannot post stuff you have taken from here without attribution. I've added that -- You probably have different namespaces

Comment: @Jimi answer me please in the older thread.  I asked there how to save the downloaded images to the hard disk? it's now working but I can't find where the images have been downloaded to on the hard disk if at all.