# Why when downloading images using httpclient it's not downloading the images at once but downloading some images then hold for some second?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

This code comes from here:
[How to download files using HttpClient with a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103)

When I click the Start Download button it's hanging then after some seconds downloading 7 images files then hanging again for some seconds like 10-15 then downloading another 7 images and so on.

I have in the List list 200 links.

but instead downloading them one by one at once it's hanging each time for some seconds.

this is the form1 usage:

```
using Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms;
using System.Text;

namespace Downloading_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBoxRadarPath.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.RadarFolder;
        }

        internal List<string> Sites()
        {
            Radar radar = new Radar(textBoxRadarPath.Text);
            radar.PrepareLinks();

            foreach (var link in radar.links)
            {
                list.Add(link);
            }
            // [...] add more URLs
            return list;
        }

        IProgress<ResourceDownloader.ProgressReport>? downloadProgress = null;
        CancellationTokenSource? cts = null;

        private void Updater(ResourceDownloader.ProgressReport progress)
        {
            StringBuilder log = new(1024);
            if (progress.Site.Completed)
            {
                log.Append($"Success! \t {progress.Site.Url}\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                log.Append($"Failed! \t {progress.Site.Url}\r\n");
                log.Append($"\tReason: {progress.Site.Ex?.Message}\r\n");
            }
            logger.AppendText(log.ToString());
            progressBar.Value = progress.PercentageComplete;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        int counter = 0;
        private async void btnStartDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ResourceDownloader.IsBusy) return;
            var sites = Sites();

            // This collection will contain the status (and data) of all downloads in th end
            List<ResourceDownloader.WebData>? downloads = null;

            using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                downloadProgress = new Progress<ResourceDownloader.ProgressReport>(Updater);
                downloads = await ResourceDownloader.Download(downloadProgress, sites, cts);
            }
        }

        private void btnCancelDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnDownloadFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadarFolderDialog();
        }

        private void RadarFolderDialog()
        {
            VistaFolderBrowserDialog dlg = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
            dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (!dlg.SelectedPath.EndsWith("Radar"))
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(dlg.SelectedPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dlg.SelectedPath + "\\Radar");
                    }

                    Properties.Settings.Default.RadarFolder = dlg.SelectedPath;// + "\\Radar";
                    textBoxRadarPath.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;// + "\\Radar";
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
                else
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.RadarFolder = dlg.SelectedPath;
                    textBoxRadarPath.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the class ResourceDownloader

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Downloading_Files
{
    public class ResourceDownloader
    {

        private static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> client = new(() => {
            HttpClientHandler handler = CreateHandler(autoRedirect: true);

            var client = new HttpClient(handler, true) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            // Keep true if you download resources from different collections of URLs each time
            // Remove or set to false if you use the same URLs multiple times and frequently
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
            return client;
        }, true);

        private static HttpClientHandler CreateHandler(bool autoRedirect)
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = autoRedirect,
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };
        }

        public record WebData(string Url, byte[]? Data, bool Completed = true, Exception? Ex = null);
        public record ProgressReport(WebData Site, int PercentageComplete);

        private static object syncObj = new object();
        private static ConcurrentBag<WebData> processed = default!;
        private static int progressCount = 0;
        private static int totalCount = 0;

        public static bool IsBusy { get; internal set; } = false;

        public static async Task<List<WebData>> Download(IProgress<ProgressReport> progress, IList<string> sites, CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            processed = new ConcurrentBag<WebData>();
            progressCount = 0;
            totalCount = sites.Count;

            try
            {
                ParallelOptions options = new()
                {
                    // If it's a single web site, set a value that doesn't get you black-listed
                    // Otherwise, increase the value 
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8,
                    CancellationToken = cts.Token
                };

                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(sites, options, async (site, token) => {
                    try
                    {
                        var dataBytes = await client.Value.GetByteArrayAsync(site, token);
                        ReportProgress(progress, dataBytes, site, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ReportProgress(progress, null, site, ex);
                    }
                });
            }
            // To Debug / Log
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { Debug.Print("The operation was canceled"); }
            finally { IsBusy = false; }
            return processed.ToList();
        }

        private static void ReportProgress(IProgress<ProgressReport> progress, byte[]? data, string site, Exception? ex)
        {
            lock (syncObj)
            {
                progressCount += 1;
                var percentage = progressCount * 100 / totalCount;
                WebData webData = new(site, data, ex is null, ex);
                processed.Add(webData);
                progress.Report(new ProgressReport(webData, percentage));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont ask multiple questions and try to be focus in your problem

Comment: Seven, right? This can't be a coincidence: `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8`

Comment: Not sure if the HttpClient still relies on the global servicePoint but if it does checkout DefaultConnectionLimit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0