# Ram not released after finishing multiple concurrent httpget requests with HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, performance, console, httpclient, ram

I wrote this code

```
Console.Write("Input first BIOS version to find: ");
int firstVersion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new Exception("Input something valid"));

Console.Write("Input last BIOS version to find: ");
int lastVersion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new Exception("Input something valid"));

Console.Write("Begin at id: ");
int startIndex = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new Exception("Input a valid number"));

Console.Write("End at id: ");
float endIndex = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new Exception("Input a valid number"));

using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

for (int currentVersion = firstVersion; currentVersion <= lastVersion; currentVersion++)
{
    int iterationsCount = 0;
    var totalIterations = endIndex - startIndex;

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var activeLinks = new List<string>();

    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
    {
        iterationsCount++;

        tasks.Add(TestUrl(i, activeLinks, currentVersion));

        if (i % 1000 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Currently at: #{i} ({iterationsCount / totalIterations * 100.0:0.00}%)");
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            tasks.Clear();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished, results:\n");

    if (activeLinks.Count > 0)
        activeLinks.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"Version {currentVersion} not found.");
}

Console.ReadLine();

async Task TestUrl(int i, List<string> activeLinks, int currentVersion)
{
    string url = $"https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/GamingNB/Image/BIOS/{i}/G713QRAS{currentVersion}.zip?model=ROG%20Strix%20G17%20G713";

    var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        activeLinks.Add(url + " >> ONLINE");
}
```

To scan all these generated urls to see if I can find an older version of my BIOS because I can't find it manually, it's just a simple project to solve a personal problem

But the reason of this post is the RAM usage, after finishing the scan of one version and trying to scan the next one, the ram used is not released, it acumulates and after trying 5 versions or so, the app is killed by the kernel to avoid RAM hogging I guess

So I don't understand where exactly is the bug, because even after the app finishes it's loops (I tested it with 2 versions scans only), then 1.XX GB of ram were used and not released, the CPU usage was near to 0% but the ram kept some data allocated, I don't know what this data is and I'm really curious about why this happens.

Only after pressing enter and the app gets closed, the ram is released. So, something must be holding data there unnecesarily. Somebody knows what is it?

Btw: I run multiple concurrent get requests to speed up the process, otherwise it will take forever to try multiple versions.

Comment: Have you considered using the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API? It allows to limit the degree of parallelism, which might help at keeping the memory usage under control.

Comment: See an example about `Parallel.ForEachAsync()` + HttpClient configuration here: [How to download files using HttpClient with a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103) -- Read also the comments in code

Comment: `using var result =` also there is no reason for GC to release memory unless someone else wants to use it, so why would you expect RAM usage to go back down? As a side note, have you considered using `HEAD` rather than `GET` requests to reduce pressure on the target server? Also in your `if (i % 1000 == 0)` you can just do `tasks.Remove(await Task.WhenAny(tasks));` rather waiting for the whole lot to finish.