# a callback in a multithreaded application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My application processes the directory (each file in a separate thread) and displays information on the screen as it runs (I use richtextbox).

There is my code:

```
class FilesHandler
{
    private List<string> PathesOfFiles = new List<string>();

    public void LoadPathes(string pathOfDirectory)
    {
        string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathOfDirectory);
        foreach (string filename in allfiles)
        {
            PathesOfFiles.Add(filename);
        }
    }

    public void HandleEachFile(RichTextBox RTB)
    {
        foreach (string path in PathesOfFiles)
        {
            new Thread(() => { CalculateThread(RTB, path); }).Start();
        }
    }

    private void CalculateThread(RichTextBox RTB, string path)
    {
        Action action2 = () => RTB.Text += DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\t";
        if (RTB.InvokeRequired)
        {
            RTB.Invoke(action2);
        }
        else
        {
            action2();
        }

        List<string> resultLog = new List<string>();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        resultLog.Add(GetFileName(path) + " {" + string.Join(", ", CountBytes(path)) + " } ");
        stopwatch.Stop();
        resultLog.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");

        if (RTB.InvokeRequired)
        {
            RTB.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                RTB.Text += String.Join("", resultLog) + '\n';
            }
            ));
        }
        else
        {
            RTB.Text += String.Join("", resultLog) + '\n';
        }
    }

    private string GetFileName(string path)
    {
        return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
    }

    private ulong[] CountBytes(string filename)
    {
        ulong[] Bytes = new ulong[256];

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096 * 1000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(filename))
            while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; Bytes[buffer[i++]]++) ;

        return Bytes;
    }
}
```

I've been doing the output in each thread using Control.Invoke, but my mentor told me to make a callback, but I don't understand how to do it, since I haven't worked with it before.
Thanks!!!

Comment: [Progress<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) -- Something similar: [How to download files using HttpClient with a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554087/7444103) (see the `ReportProgress()` and `Updater()` methods) -- You may also want to use Tasks instead of starting Threads. The parallel async method used there may be easily adapted to your use-case

Comment: @Jimi I also made implementations via Task, Async/await, but the method with threads is faster, maybe because of the specifics of the implementation.

Comment: @Jimi, Could you, if it's not difficult, make a callback in my code, please? I've recently started learning c# and I can't figure out the example with the web client yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with `InvokeRequired`.

Instead use more modern methods such as a `Progress<T>` to return progress status to the UI, and/or `await` to get you back on to the UI thread.

Hand off `CountBytes` to a threadpool thread using `Task.Run` in order not to block the rest of the loop.

Also:

- Use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`, and `AddRange` instead of looping.
- Use a `List<ulong>` for the counts of bytes received.

```cs
class FilesHandler
{
    private List<string> PathesOfFiles = new List<string>();

    public void LoadPathes(string pathOfDirectory)
    {
        PathesOfFiles.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathOfDirectory))
    }

    public void HandleEachFile(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        foreach (string path in PathesOfFiles)
        {
            Task.Run(() => CalculateThread(progress, path));
        }
    }

    private async Task CalculateThread(IProgress<string> progress, string path)
    {
       progress.Report(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\t");

        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var bytes = await CountBytes(path);
        stopwatch.Stop();

        progress.Report((Path.GetFileName(path) + " {" + string.Join(", ", bytes) + " } ");
        progress.Report((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
    }

    private async Task<List<ulong>> CountBytes(string filename)
    {
        List<ulong> allBytesRead = new(256);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096 * 1000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(filename))
            while ((bytesRead = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; allBytesRead.Add(buffer[i++]);

        return allBytesRead;
    }
}
```

You can now simply do

```cs
HandleEachFile(new Progress<string>(str => RTB.Text += str);
```

Note that there are obviously much better ways to get all the bytes in a file, I assume this is for an exercise.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have an exception:
"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" в mscorlib.dll
how can i fix it?
it appears on this line
var bytes = await CountBytes(path);

Comment: See newedits...